# odd behavior when substituting parts of a string within a for loop

Tags: r, string, dataframe, gsub

I'm trying to replace a series of numbers in a character string with information that comes from a dataframe.

My string comes from a text file that I imported using the readr package as follows: `read_file("Human.txt")`
I've checked the class, it is character. The string contains the following information (I've named it treeString):

`"(1,2,((((3),884),(((((519,((516,517),(515,(518,(513,514))))),((((((((458,(457,(455,456))),459),(502,(454,(453,(451,452)))))"`

My dataframe (labels.csv) was originally in factor format, but I changed the format of the second column to character using the following command: `labels[,2] = as.character(labels[,2])`. It looks like this

```
     v1     v2
1    1      name1
2    2      name2
3    3      name3
```

My goal is to substitute every number in the string with the corresponding name (i.e. V2) in the dataframe. This should result in the following:

`"(name1,name2,((((name3),884),(((((519,((516,517),(515,(518,(513,514))))),((((((((458,(457,(455,456))),459),(502,(454,(453,(451,452)))))"`

Here is the code I am using to accomplish this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(labels)){
  gsub(as.character(i), labels[i,2], treeString)
}
```

The weird thing is that if I run the gsub() command on its own (with specified numbers - eg. 2) it does the substitution, however, when I run it in a loop it does not substitute the numbers.

Comment: In your code, you are not assigning the results back to treeString variable

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Kumar Manglam in the comments, you forgot to assign the result of `gsub()` back to `treeString`.

There is something else you should be aware of: The way you specified the regular expression in your question it will also replace patterns like `"(241)"` with `"(name24name1)"`. To avoid this behaviour, you should check whether the numbers you want to replace are preceded by a comma or opening parenthesis *and* succeeded by a comma or closing parenthesis:

```
# Option1
for(i in 1:nrow(labelnames)){
   reg_pattern <- paste0("(?<=[(,])(", i, ")(?=[),])")
   treeString  <- gsub(reg_pattern, labelnames$v2[i], treeString, perl=T)
}
```

Another, nicer, option is drop the `for`-loop and do it all at once:

```
# Option2
reg_pattern <- paste0("(?<=[(,])([1-", nrow(labelnames), "])(?=[),])")
treeString  <- gsub(reg_pattern, "name\\1", treeString, perl=T)

# Result
treeString
# "(name1,name2,((((name3),884),(((((519,((516,517),(515,(518,(513,514))))),((((((((458,(457,(455,456))),459),(502,(454,(453,(451,452)))))"
```

---

**Data**

```
 treeString <- "(1,2,((((3),884),(((((519,((516,517),(515,(518,(513,514))))),((((((((458,(457,(455,456))),459),(502,(454,(453,(451,452)))))"
 labelnames <- structure(list(v1 = 1:3, v2 = c("name1", "name2", "name3")), .Names = c("v1", "v2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Sorry, but in this case nothing happens, i.e. nothing is replaced. This is the case when I run the lines on their own and when I run them in a loop

Comment: Do we have the same data input? Because for me it works fine